# How can I compare three elements in js?

Tags: javascript

When inner has the same text, it doesn't return true. I tried to make variables with these values, doesn't work

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
if (btns[0].innerHTML == btns[1].innerHTML == btns[2].innerHTML ){
    //do smth
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to compare one and then the other like this

```js
if (first === second && second === third) {}
```

in your case it would be like this

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
if (
btns[0].innerHTML == btns[1].innerHTML &&
btns[1].innerHTML == btns[2].innerHTML){
    //do smth
}
```